# Cannot find missing com.css maven artifacts in spring tools suite

Tags: java, maven, repository, spring-tool-suite, artifact

I am trying to compile a Maven project in the Spring Tools Suite version 3.7 and Maven version 3.3.3.

It fails with

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project
com.ccs:ccs-nbook-service:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved:
com.ccs:ccs-common-service:jar:R.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT,
com.ccs:ccs-common-ui:jar:R.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT,
com.ccs:ccs-common-core:jar:R.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact 
com.ccs:ccs-common-service:jar:R.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in central
```

I have looked online and cannot locate these maven repositories.

Does anyone know where I can get these repositories or how I can fix this problem please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not find these jar files listed above in the following link

```
http://mvnrepository.com/
```

I guess these jars may be developed by someone, but they are not still very stable, so the version name of jar is end up with `snapshot`

if you could get or find theses jar files, you can install these jars into your local maven repo or upload them to your central repo

The command of installing the jar file to local repo is listed below

```
mvn install:install-file  -Dfile=D:/jar/xxx.jar  -DgroupId=xxx.xxx  -DartifactId=xxx -Dversion=x.x -Dpackaging=jar
```